# Nugets install DotLiquid failed for .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, dotliquid

I'm new to Nugets install and DotLiquid, and I'm getting the following error when installing DotLiquid with Nugets:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'DotLiquid 2.0.64'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package DotLiquid
```

[From here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38376277-does-dotliquid-support-net-framework-4-5), it says DotLiquid does support .NET Framework 4.5, however I don't know how to "*download the nuget package*", as the [download link from dotliquid](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/downloads) only show packages more than 4 years old.

How to fix it?

PS. If I try `Get-Package DotLiquid`, I'll get this:

```
PM> Get-Package DotLiquid
No packages installed.
```

**UPDATE:**

I've just installed the up-to-date NuGet extension (and restarted my MS VS several times), but the problem remain the same. My current NuGet version:

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 2.12.0.817
```

Comment: Is your installed NuGet extension up-to-date?

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to *Tools > Extensions and Updates...*, and check if NuGet appears in the *Updates* category.

Comment: @Stijn Thx. Just updated as per your help. Problem still remains. OP updated.

Comment: The package says is supports 4.5.1.  Try upgrading the framework of your project to 4.5.1 and try again.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, YEP! that works! Thx!!

Comment: *Update* The package now support .net 4.5.